# Proving that a function is a contraction map

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence

I have a function defined by:
$F(X) = a \left( \frac{X-A}{\|X-A\|_2} - \frac{B-X}{\|B-X\|_2} \right)  $ with $X,A,B \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ $a\in \mathbb{R}_+ $. Is this a contraction map? If yes I want to prove it. I tried $\|F(Y) - F(X)\|\le\alpha\|Y-X\| $ with  $ 0 \le \alpha < 1$ numerically thousands of times with random $X,Y$ and the disequality is always satisfied. 
Any suggestion ??

Comment: $F$ is not well defined at $X=A$ or $X=B$.

Comment: Yes, I had to say that $X \neq A, X \neq B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=B=(1,0,0)$ and let $a=1000000$ (because I can). Consider $X=(0,0,0)$ and $Y=(2,0,0)$ then

- $\|Y-X\|=2$
- $F(Y)=(2000000,0,0)$
- $F(X)=(-2000000,0,0)$

and so $F(Y)-F(X)=(4000000,0,0)$ hence $$\|F(Y)-F(X)\|=4000000>\alpha 2=\alpha \|Y-X\|$$

for all $\alpha\in[0,1)$

This is not a contraction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so can I impose a condition on $a$ to guarantee contraction?

Comment: In the 1-dimensional problem, the expression inside the parentheses can only take the values $0,2$ or $-2$, and so $F(Y)-F(X)$ can only take values in $\{-4a,-2a,0,2a,4a\}$ hence $\|F(Y)-F(X)\|=0,2a$ or $4a$. Given that $\|Y-X\|$ can take any value in the positive reals, no choice of $a$ will suffice.

Comment: I think you mean the opposite, if $\|F(Y)-F(X)\|$ is limited to be maximum $4a$, it means that for large $\|Y-X\| $the contraction condition is satisfied.

Comment: Given any $a\geq 0$ and $\alpha\in[0,1)$, I can find an $X$ and $Y$ close together such that $\|F(Y)-F(X)\|> \alpha\|Y-X\|$ because the first just depends on the parities of the differences $X-A,X-B,Y-A,Y-B$. The easiest way to prove $F$ is not a contraction mapping is to note that it is not continuous because its image is not connected, but its domain is connected. Every contraction mapping is continuous - contradiction.